# I can not pass data from one View Controller to another

Tags: ios, swift, api, uikit, tableview

Could you help me with my code. I can not pass ma data on prepare segue. // cannot assign value of type Response to type Meals. I don't know what I do wrong. I just need a help with line prepare for segue. It is a last line of code. Will be glad for any help. thank you!

```
struct Response: Codable {
var meals: [Meals]?
```

}

```
struct Meals: Codable {
var strMeal: String?
var strMealThumb: String?
var idMeal: String?
```

}

```
class MealsViewController: UIViewController {

//var results: Response?

var meals : Meals = Meals()

@IBOutlet weak var mealImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var idLbl: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   
    nameLbl.text = meals.strMeal
    idLbl.text = meals.idMeal
   
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var resultsData: Response?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    
    getResultData {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
     }
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
}
```

}

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    resultsData?.meals?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    let meal = resultsData?.meals
    cell.textLabel?.text = meal![indexPath.row].strMeal
    
    return cell
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? MealsViewController {
           destination.meals = resultsData // cannot assign value of type Response to type Meals
        }
    }
```

Please check it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `meals` should be outside the `viewDidLoad`

It should be as below.

```
class MealsViewController : UIViewController {

    var meals : Meals = Meals()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         print("your meal name is==\(meals.strMeal ?? "")")
    }

}
```

Comment: Or, the line `destination.meal = resultsData?.meals` should be changed to `destination.results = resultsData`.